# Error while looping through multiple tables in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this code(sql server 2008)

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable

'
IF ''?'' LIKE ''%_records%''
BEGIN

Update ? set Status = ''expired'' where expire_date_time <= getdate()
END'
```

When I execute this query, it updates the tables, but it displays an error like:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Invalid column name 'expire_date_time'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Invalid column name 'expire_date_time'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Invalid column name 'expire_date_time'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Invalid column name 'expire_date_time'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Invalid column name 'expire_date_time'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Invalid column name 'expire_date_time'.
```

Why it is so? Can someone guide me with correct code? I want to put that code in event is it possible, so it will check the condition after particular time interval.

Comment: does every single table that contains `_records_` in its name has the `expire_date_time` column?

Comment: I would hazard a guess that it is because you don't have a column named "expire_date_time" in a few of your databases.

Comment: yes. example: username_records like if username is jason then tablename is jason_records. and each table have expire_date_time column.

Comment: well, you should look for every single table that contains `_records` in its name and make sure that everyone has that column, because it appears that some don't

Comment: yes i did checked each of them have that column. that is why i am unable to figure out whats going wrong here.

Comment: SQL Server tends not to make mistakes about things like this.   Can you create a script that reproduces this behavior?   Otherwise, I have to believe you made a mistake when you checked all the tables for that column.   You probably missed a typo somewhere.

Comment: Maybe you have Case Sensitive collation and the field is EXPIRE_DATE_TIME?

Comment: if you believe you verified everything, put your query in a variable and output to window; extract all those queries from output and run in a separate window; you should see the issue yourself;

Comment: Try this query to find the table(s) you didn't think about. select * 
from sys.tables
where name like '%_records%'

Comment: my problem is, it performs the required updations in tables but it displays error after that. i put only 2-3 tables there in database to test everything is perfect there is no typo at all.

Answer (score 0):

Trap the error with TRY/CATCH and RAISE (or THROW) a custom error message that includes the tablename (`?`) and then you'll know which table is missing the column.

Comment: my problem is, it performs the required updations in tables but it displays error after that. i put only 2-3 tables there in database to test everything is perfect there is no typo at all.

Comment: Well yes, this is what I would expect.   Your code runs on every table, and when it finds that column, it works, and when it doesn't, it raises that error.  So why is that a problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `IF` statement isn't going to do anything to prevent SQL Server from parsing the command. For example, try:

```
IF 1=0
BEGIN
    SELECT blah FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
END
```

You'll still get an error.

Also, having tables like `jason_records` is a pretty horrible idea.

Another way that you could accomplish this is to only do the `UPDATE` in dynamic code:

```
DECLARE
    @table_name    SYSNAME,
    @table_schema  SYSNAME,
    @sql           NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE CURSOR tables_cursor FOR
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C ON
    C.TABLE_CATALOG = T.TABLE_CATALOG AND
    C.TABLE_SCHEMA = T.TABLE_SCHEMA AND
    C.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME AND
    C.COLUMN_NAME = 'expire_date_time'
WHERE
    T.TABLE_NAME LIKE '%_records'

OPEN tables_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM tables_cursor INTO @table_schema, @table_name

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    SELECT @sql = 'UPDATE ' + QUOTENAME(@table_schema) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@table_name) + ' SET status = 'expired' WHERE expire_date_time <= GETDATE()'

    EXEC (@sql)

    FETCH NEXT FROM tables_cursor INTO @table_schema, @table_name
END

CLOSE tables_cursor

DEALLOCATE tables_cursor
```

Comment: my problem is, it performs the required updations in tables but it displays error after that. i put only 2-3 tables there in database to test everything is perfect there is no typo at all.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately sp_MSforeachtable is unsupported code. It may contain bugs which will never be corrected. Try []

```
...
update ? set [Status] = ''expired'' where [expire_date_time] <= getdate()
...
```